# SharePoint-Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I was just wondering if it's at all possible to create a SharePoint-Hosted App and call code in a class library?

The idea is the class library will do all the leg work and the .aspx pages in the app will simply call the functions and pass in parameters and ultimately retrieve a string return value for me to display.

Edit -
The app will be written in Visual Studio 2013 and the idea was I could add a class library to the solution and (within the aspx pages in the app) call the class library I have in the solution. The class library will be written in C#.

Comment: "Call code in a class library" - what do you mean by that? A DLL, COM DLL, or what? What language is the "code" written in?

Comment: Sorry, should have expanded this a bit more...  Making too many assumptions.

Comment: Well, you still haven't explained it.

Comment: The app will be written in Visual Studio 2013 and the idea was I could add a class library to the solution and (within the aspx pages in the app) call the class library I have in the solution.  The class library will be written in C#.

Comment: How about you edit your question and add the info, don't just leave that as a comment.

Comment: I've updated the original post :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy or call any back end code from SharePoint hosted app. You have access only to client side code - javascript, html, css. Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2013 has three types of apps.
1 Provided - Hosted App
2 Auto - hosted APP
This two kinda are cloud based apps
It is prefereed hosting model for almost all types of apps

1. Sharepoint - Hosted app
   It is good only for smaller apps & resource app.
   **It is sharepoint based, no server side code**
   Automatically hosted in sharepoint